# Как нарисовать движущийся треугольник в WinForms на C#

Tags: c#

Возникла необходимость написать форму на C#, в которой при нажатии на кнопку «Начать» будет двигаться равносторонний треугольник, отбивающийся от краев формы. Подскажите пожалуйста!

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=54GnbNEvLTk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, у вас на форме должна быть кнопка и панель как область для рисования. Создайте Bitmap и присвойте его в BackgroundImage панели. Получите экземпляр графики данного Bitmap и рисуйте треугольник через [DrawPolygon](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawpolygon?view=netframework-4.8), двигайте его как вам нужно (возможно, понадобятся [полярные координаты](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7868740)) и выполняйте метод Invalidate панели, чтобы изменения отражались на ней.